# Foreign key ON UPDATE CASCADE in eclipselink

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

How to create a foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE in eclipselink.
Can anyone explain how to create such foreign key

Is this feature available in eclipselink?

srini

Comment: Did you mean update cascade in jpa?

Comment: @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye yes, is that supported in JPA (eclipselink)

Comment: Yes, use CascadeTpye.ALL or CascadeType.MERGE keyword

Comment: See my post that may be reference for you

Comment: @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye i tried using CascadeType.MERGE keyword, but in the foreign key constraint ON UPDATE CASCADE is missing. I have posted my code below; is there anything missing in that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these properties **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** or **cascade = CascadeType.MERGE** when you want to cascade update. see sample;

```
   @Entity
   class Employee {

      @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
      private Address address;

  }
```